# Get the number of concurrent users in Apache?

Tags: linux, apache

We want to know how many concurrent users the apache is serving at one time? Can I do it by installing some statistics tools? I tried webalizer but it only shows hourly hits, not the number of users. Or I have to analyze the log using some tools?

Comment: Apache Module mod_status would be the standard tool I think

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check out [Apache Top](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/monitor-your-website-in-real-time-with-apachetop/).

Or you can write your own script from the command line that just check the number of current connections on the port Apache is running on (usually 80), for example:

```
netstat -plan | grep :80
```

Or, if you just want the number:

```
netstat -plan | grep :80 | wc -l
```

This could ideally be done through a cron (e.g., run every minute and check number of connections, average over time, etc.).

Comment: I think the "grep :80" is not working as expected, more if you have services like tomcat or couchbase which run on ports "80XX"...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small script that I use. I have an SSL based site, so I'm checking the active connections on port 443.  You might want to update 443 to 80, depending on what you would like to monitor.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 <refresh time>" ; exit 1; }

while true
do
        clear;
        echo "Number of Active Connections:";
        netstat -an | grep 443 | grep tcp | grep -v 0.0.0.0 | grep -v ::: | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f12 | sort | uniq | wc -l;
        echo;
        echo "Current Active IP's:";
        netstat -an | grep 443 | grep tcp | grep -v 0.0.0.0 | grep -v ::: | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f12 | sort | uniq;
        sleep $1;
done
```

One thing to keep in mind is that, if you're behind a VIP, then your web server will only see 1 IP (the one from the VIP).  Since this script is checking for unique IP's, it will always show 1 connection.  One way to resolve this is to remove the text "| uniq".